# Removing rows if they occur within a certain time of each other by a group value in R

Tags: r, time, data-cleaning, lubridate, posixct

My data `df` looks like the following:

```
Row    Timestamp            ID
1    0020-06-29 12:14:00     B 
2    0020-06-29 12:27:00     A 
3    0020-06-29 12:27:22     B  
4    0020-06-29 12:28:30     A 
5    0020-06-29 12:43:00     B 
6    0020-06-29 12:44:00     C 
7    0020-06-29 12:45:00     B 
8    0020-06-29 12:55:00     A 
9    0020-06-29 12:57:00     C 
10   0020-06-29 13:04:00     B
```

The `Timestamp` indicates the date and time of a reading, and `ID` the tag identification code.

What I am trying to do is remove any `Timestamp` by the same `ID` that occurs within 5 minutes of the previous Timestamp. So, although `ID` A is seen in `Row` 2 and `Row` 4, since the two rows of the dataframe occur within 5 minutes of each other, we would remove `Row` 4 but keep `Row` 2 and `Row` 8, which for ID A occurs 18 minutes later.

Update: The first timestamp should take precedent and all subsequent timestamps should be either kept or removed from then on. So, if we have 3 timestamps corresponding to the same ID and with a time interval of 4.5 minutes and 2 minutes, respectively, between timestamp 1 and 2 and timestamp 2 and 3, I would like remove timestamp 2 and keep 1 and 3. This way the next timestamp we keep would be the one that occurs at least 5 minutes after timestamp 3, and so on.

I have tried the following:

```
first_date <- df$Timestamp[1:(length(df$Timestamp)-1)]
second_date <- df$Timestamp[2:length(df$Timestamp)]
second_gap <- difftime(second_date, first_date, units="mins")

dup_index <- second_gap>5 # set this as a 5-minute threshold
dup_index <- c(TRUE, dup_index)
df_cleaned <- df[dup_index, ]
```

But this deletes all observations within 5-minutes of each other and does not take into account the `ID`. I would usually just `subset` but I am working with around 180 unique `ID`s.

Comment: Your description of the problem appears to be not complete: Suppose 3 timestamps corresponding to the same ID and with a time interval of 4.5 minutes and 2 minutes, respectively between timestamp 1 and 2 and timestamp 2 and 3. Should timestamp 3 be removed, in spite of the fact that is within the 5 minutes time interval regarding the previous timestamp?

Comment: Hi Paul, thank you for your response. You are correct, I should have said that the first timestamp will take precedent and all subsequent timestamps should be either kept or removed from then on, if that makes sense. So ideally we would remove timestamp 2 and keep 1 and 3. This way the next timestamp we keep would be the one that occurs at least 5 minutes after timestamp 3, and so on. Apologies for being unclear.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @bill_scoresby. Could you please update your example with the situation I identified and how you would like that to be treated?

Comment: Okay, it has been updated. Should I proceed with trying the code in your answer? Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, @bill_scoresby, I have just tried my code with the date you provided above, and the output is the one shown below. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Hi Paul. Yes. I just ran it on my full data set and it works great. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing that what I comment above does not occur, a possible solution is the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

elapsed <- function(x)
{
  y <- abs(as.duration(x[2:length(x)] %--% x[1:(length(x)-1)]))
  y >= 5*60
} 

df %>% 
  group_split(ID) %>% 
  map_dfr(~ .[c(T, if (nrow(.) > 1) elapsed(.$Timestamp)),]) %>% 
  arrange(Row)
```

The output:

```
# A tibble: 8 × 3
    Row Timestamp           ID   
  <int> <chr>               <chr>
1     1 0020-06-29 12:14:00 B    
2     2 0020-06-29 12:27:00 A    
3     3 0020-06-29 12:27:22 B    
4     5 0020-06-29 12:43:00 B    
5     6 0020-06-29 12:44:00 C    
6     8 0020-06-29 12:55:00 A    
7     9 0020-06-29 12:57:00 C    
8    10 0020-06-29 13:04:00 B
```